# React Native - Google Reverse Geocoding Doesn't Work in Production

Tags: ios, react-native, google-maps, google-api, expo

I am using Google's geocoding API to get lat/lng from an address.

This works when I am running the app in Expo, but when I compile for iOS, the request fails.

This is really hard to debug as I have to rebuild the app and submit to TestFlight every change I make. It works when I run `expo run:ios` and run the dev build in the simulator.

Here's my code

```
    const fetchCoordinates = async () => {
      try {

        const apiKey = Util.getPlatformAPIKey();
        const googleApiUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${encodeURIComponent(address)}&key=${apiKey}`;

        const response = await fetch(googleApiUrl, {
          mode: "no-cors",
          redirect: "follow",
          method: "GET",
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          return;
        } else {
          setStatus("Response from geocoding API ok");\
        }

        const data = await response.json();

        if (data.results.length > 0) {
          const {lat, lng} = data.results[0].geometry.location;
          return {latitude: lat, longitude: lng};
        } else {
          return undefined;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching coordinates:", error);
      }
    };
```

Seems to just return undefined. Google Cloud Console is not showing any errors.

Is iOS blocking requests to googleapis.com? I have NSAllowsArbitraryLoads set to true

```
"NSAppTransportSecurity": {
    "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads": true
}
```

Comment: Did you have any API key restrictions that might have affected your prod build?

Comment: @Yrll no, I disabled the restrictions while i was debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `console.dir` was in a try block which throws an error in production (but not in dev/simulator)